# Identify a GCD thread

Tags: objective-c, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

I have written a Core Data abstraction class which holds the persistent store, object model and object context. To make the multithreading easier, I have written the accessor for the object context so that it returns a instance that is only available for the current thread by using `[NSThread currentThread]` to identify the threads.

This works perfectly as long as I don't use GCD, which I want to use as replacement for the old NSThread's. So my question is, how do I identify a GCD thread? The question applies for both iOS and Mac OS X but I guess that its the same for both platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check whether dispatch_get_current_queue() returns anything. I like Jeremy's idea of transitioning to a CD-context-per-queue instead of CD-context-per-thread model using the queue's context storage though.

Comment: The problem is that there must be one object context per thread to allow multithreading. A GCD queue can afair spawn multiple threads at dispatch time?!

Comment: GCD queues other than the global concurrent queues are serial, i.e. one thread at a time. Unless the requirement is that it must always be *the same underlying pthread*, it should be ok.

Comment: -1 Core Data requires that the underlying thread be the same. Any way to force GCD to keep reusing the same thread in a serial queue?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can store the CD context for each thread in the GCD context [using dispatch_set_context()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW34)

Answer (score 0):

The contextForCurrentThread helper method in Magical Record is very similar to what to said (i.e. keep one context per thread). The GCD execution block, while running on a single queue, can potentially run on any thread managed by GCD, which will cause some random crashes. Check this article: http://saulmora.com/2013/09/15/why-contextforcurrentthread-doesn-t-work-in-magicalrecord/